# How to import two component but same name from two libraries?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next

I need Tooltip component from two libraries. For example

```
import { Tooltip } from "react-leaflet";
import { Tooltip } from "recharts";
```

But the same name of Tooltip of two libraries, I get an error. How to import Tooltip without error.

Answer (score 23):

```
import { Tooltip as LeafletTooltip } from "react-leaflet";
```

And then using `<LeafletTooltip>` below

Answer (score 11):

```
import { Tooltip as ReactLeafletTooltip} from "react-leaflet";
import { Tooltip as RechartsTooltip} from "recharts";
```

then use it in render as

```
<RechartsTooltip/>
<ReactLeafletTooltip/>
```